# Hiding and showing groups of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a page where all items of class 'div_title_item' are initially hidden. Base on some paginator logic I would then like to show some of them.

```
// initially
$(".div_title_item").hide(); // this works fine
```

Now the showing part. I tried below but it didn't work.

```
// on some event for example
var collection = $(".div_title_item");
collection[0].show();
collection[1].show();
// etc...
```

Nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/t4gZc/)**

Make them jQuery objects by doing the following.

```
$(collection[0]).show();
$(collection[1]).show();
```

Otherwise they are just standard `DOM` elements and wont have access to jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1):

Doing things like this:

```
collection[0]
```

Gives you the underlying DOM objects and they don't know what `.show()` means. An easy approach is to use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) to access the `<div>` you want:

```
var collection = $(".div_title_item");
collection.eq(0).show();
collection.eq(1).show();
```

You could also use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
collection.filter(':eq(1)').show();
```